# How to calculate if scrollbar will show (recursive problem)

Tags: javascript

Given a container like this:

```
.container {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

You would expect that either a vertical or horizontal scrollbar will appear if the content width or height is `> 100px`.

However that's not the case, because if you make the width `101px` then this will result in a horizontal scrollbar, **which reduces the available height** and also causes a vertical scrollbar:

> Note: This problem applies to desktop style scrollbars not the ones on
> touch devices which **overlay** while scrolling. (You can turn desktop
> style scrollbars on in MacOS settings even on a laptop)

```css
.container {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.content1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
}

.content2 {
  width: 101px;
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content1"></div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="content2"></div>
</div>
```

If you have desktop style scrollbars then you should see this:

[image: 2 divs - one with scrollbars and one with none]

As mentioned even though only width changed, both scrollbars then appeared.

So how do we programmatically calculate if the scrollbars will appear? Without DOM queries. Given that this problem seems to be recursive?

```
const viewportWidth = 100
const viewportHeight = 100

const contentWidth = 101 // overflow
const contentHeight = 100

const scrollbarSize = 16

// WRONG, this should subtract `scrollbarSize` IF `hasHScroll` is `true`
// but `hasHScroll` also relies on the result of `hasVScroll`.
const hasVScroll = contentHeight > viewportHeight

const hasHScroll = contentWidth - (hasVScroll ? scrollbarSize : 0)
```

Comment: well scrollbar takes up space in the container. So if you add it reduces the height so it has to adjust. Not sure what you are after. What do you need to know that it has scrollbars? That if you add content they will appear? What is the thing you are trying to solve?

Comment: I know it doesn't directly answer the question, but have you considered using floating/Mac OS style scrollbars for these (via js)? Like you mentioned it doesn't interfere with the container dimension. (Though of course it depends if it's applicable to your use case)